# How do I stop the program once I have reached a certain line?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a game in python, a game of multiple choice called "Who wants to be a millionaire?" and the problem is I want the program to stop executing the second question once the user failed to answer the first one.

```
print("What is the tallest being in existence?")

input(("If you want to see the choices just press enter. " + name))

print("Is it A, Dinosaur?")
print("B, The one and only, Giraffe")
print("C,The soul of the ocean Whale")
print("or D, None")

print("So what do you believe is the answer ? " + name + " ")

answer_1 = input()

if answer_1 == Q1_answer:
    print("Correct! You Have Earned 100,000$ ")
    score = +100000
if answer_1 != Q1_answer:
    print("Im sorry, You have lost the game.")

print("Which famous inventor was born in 1856?")

print("A Einstein")
print("B, Tesla")
print("C, Napoleon")
print("D, Newton")

answer_2 = input()

if answer_2 == Q2_answer.lower():

    print("Correct! It is Tesla Indeed, Your reached  200,000$ ")
    score = +100000
else:
    print("Sorry, wrong answer. You have lost and earned 0$. ")
```

Comment: Try using `exit()`

Comment: You should reshape your code. For example use a loop to run through the questions. Also you could store the questions, options and correct answer in a list, for example...

Comment: Please look at while loop as an option. sys.exit() may not be the best option for you. I think you want to gracefully exit the program. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-while-loops/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write your program in a better way, currently you cannot easily add questions as you will have to repeat the whole code for each new question. You can store all your questions in one list and then iterate over them. I also did not need `sys.exit()` because of the way I organized the code. Here is the code:

```
questions = [
    {
        "question": "What is the tallest being in existence?",
        "options": [
            "Is it A, Dinosaur?",
            "B, The one and only, Giraffe",
            "C,The soul of the ocean Whale",
            "or D, None"
        ],
        "correctOption": "a",
        "prize": 100_000
    },
    {
        "question": "Which famous inventor was born in 1856?",
        "options": [
            "A Einstein",
            "B, Tesla",
            "C, Napoleon",
            "D, Newton"
        ],
        "correctOption": "b",
        "prize": 100_000
    }
]

isGameWon = True
score = 0

for question in questions:
    print(question['question'])
    input("If you want to see the choices just press enter.")
    for option in question['options']:
        print(option)
    print("So what do you believe is the answer?")
    answer = input()
    if answer.lower() == question['correctOption']:
        score = score + question['prize']
        print("Correct! You Have Earned $" + str(score) + ".")
    else:
        isGameWon = False
        break

if (isGameWon):
    print("Congrats! You have won the game. You earned $" + str(score) + ".")
else:
    print("Sorry, wrong answer. You have lost and earned $0.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit the program completely you need to call the exit method.

```
import sys
...    
if answer_1 != Q1_answer:
    print("Im sorry, You have lost the game.")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: You should try and provide loops as an option instead of this.

Comment: @JoeFerndz it looks like he is a beginner. I would not write his code like that either but for now he just wants to exit a program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exit() to exit your program. I`d print a message telling the user that the program will be exited.